# two projects can't be opened anymore - can't find .project file - how can i restore my work?

Tags: html, aptana

I worked on two projects last night. This morning I opened Aptana 3 and my two projects can't be opened anymore. It alerts me that the .project file is missing. I can't find it anywhere on my mac book. How can I restore my work?
I'm greatful for your help and if you could answer very detailed because I'm a beginner with Aptana and webdesign.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can either find the .project file (which may be hidden on Mac?) or you can import your project folder into Aptana and it will create a new .project file.

`File > Import > General > Existing Folder as New Project`